# Context of JavaScript compare function of "sort"

Tags: javascript

In my "class" method I use the JavaScript "sort" function plus a compare function:

```
this.models.sort(this.comparator);
```

When the sort function calls my comparator, is it possible to define the context/"this" for 
the comparator?

I know it can be done this way:

```
var self = this;
this.models.sort(function(a, b){return self.comparator.call(self, a, b);});
```

But does somebody know a simpler way?

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
 this.models.sort(this.comparator.bind(this));
```

`bind` builds a new bound function which will be executed with the context you pass.

As this isn't compatible with IE8, the closure solution is usually adopted. But you can make it simpler :

```
var self = this;
this.models.sort(function(a, b){return self.comparator(a, b);});
```

Comment: @JanDvorak It starts at IE9.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.models.sort(this.comparator.bind(context));
```

Comment: See [Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)